# How to detect exceptions thrown by the CLR?

Tags: windows, debugging, winapi, clr

I'm using the [`WaitForDebugEvent()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681423.aspx) API to process debug events while debugging a third party application. Very often I catch an access violation thrown by the CLR (the debugee is using some .NET libraries). I see that later when I analyze the mini dump with the WinDbg. Can I detect such exception coming from the CLR immediately when `WaitForDebugEvent()` returns?

Here are the details on the caught exception:

```
EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)  
ExceptionAddress: 000007fef7e870eb (clr!EEFileLoadException::Throw+0x00000000000001ac)  
ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)  
ExceptionFlags: 00000000  
NumberParameters: 2  
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000  
   Parameter[1]: 000000000000007d  
Attempt to read from address 000000000000007d
```

Comment: It is very clear, but as somebody said before, the SO has gone to hell a long time ago. These days it's more like a pissing contest led by the people with high enough reputation to start pissing in the first place.

Comment: Well, I originally upvoted your question because I agreed that it was clear and potentially interesting. The edit leaves me more confused. I thought you were saying that when you use WaitForDebugEvent, you do not see exceptions thrown by the CLR, and were asking how to receive notification of these exceptions. Seems like a valid question to me. So where are these exception details you edited in coming from? What is the actual problem here? The imprecise use of terminology doesn't help either. When you "catch" an exception, that implies an exception handler, not WaitForDebugEvent returning TRUE

Comment: now clear. ok - you can view that ExceptionAddress - in clr.dll - this is mean "thrown by the CLR" ? so in what problem ?

Comment: however here interesting next moment - exception direct at clr!EEFileLoadException::Throw+0x00000000000001ac address ? not RaiseException(or analog) called but direct in this function code ?

Answer (score 1):

all exceptions from CLR have ExceptionCode in form 0xE0****** and NumberParameters > 3. most common, which i see - e0434352 (0xe0000000 + 'CCR') - look for example - [this](http://www.debugthings.com/2015/03/20/visual-studio-target-invocation/): -

> The Unknown exception - code e0434352 (first chance) is a big clue
>   here. If you look at the error you might see some hex that looks
>   familiar ‘0x43’ ‘0x43’ ‘0x52’ or ‘C’ ‘C’ ‘R’. No, this isn’t a homage
>   to Creedence and doesn’t mean there is a bad moon rising. This tells
>   me the errors are being thrown from the CLR runtime. Sweet. Things
>   just got a bit easier.

another common code - 0xE0434F4D (0xe0000000+'COM') - [How CLR maps SEH exceptions to managed exception types](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2009/05/14/how-clr-maps-seh-exceptions-to-managed-exception-types/)

edited:

> access violation thrown by the CLR

you mean direct STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION exception ? in this case no way detect, but i never see this in CLR direct. or when CLR throw RaiseException and in ExceptionInformation[0] -> STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION ?

Comment: The STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION.

Comment: you mean than generated by CLR managed code (not in any DLL) direct raise STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION, by invalid access memory location ? and this is "Very often" ? i not view this, but in this case you view only very common exception code, can determinate that it not in DLL, but how determinate that this is CLR genereted code - i not view ways. or you mean  STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION in some system .net DLL ?

Comment: I apologize for the incorrect previous comment. I'm talking about EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION, not STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION.

Comment: i understand you, i also mean exactly this - EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION this is same as STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION - c0000005